# Traverse path up and check/set permissions in shell script - how?

Tags: shell, permissions, script, path

In a given shell script I need to take a known path and check it upwards (to the file system root) for correct permissions. How would I split the path and walk upwards in a shell script (can be bash or a "lower common denominator")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
unset path
parts=$(pwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{for (i=1; i < NF; i++) print $i}')

for part in $parts
do
path="$path/$part"
ls -ld $path   # do whatever checking you need here
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a (ba)sh-only solution?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried ennuikiller's awk solution, it missed the current directory for me.

So, while a bit late, here's a bash-only solution:

```
foo=`pwd`
while [ "$foo" != "" ]; do
    echo $foo # work with directory here
    foo=${foo%/*}
done
```

Don't know if it's the most elegant solution, but it works.  I found a simple explanation of the string manipulation on [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/18/bash.html) and wrapped a loop around it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [ennuikiller's solution](https://superuser.com/a/65076):

```
realpath () {
    # realpath()        -- print absolute path (os.path.realpath) to $1
    #                      note: OSX does not have readlink -f
    python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])))" "${1}"
    return
}

walkpath () {
    # walkpath()        -- walk down path $1 and $cmd each component
    #   $1 : path (optional; default: pwd)
    #   $2 : cmd  (optional; default: ls -ald --color=auto)
    #https://superuser.com/a/65076 
    dir=${1:-$(pwd)}
    if [ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]; then
        cmd=${2:-"ls -ldaG"}
    else
        cmd=${2:-"ls -lda --color=auto"}
    fi
    dir=$(realpath ${dir})
    parts=$(echo ${dir} \
        | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{for (i=1; i < NF+2; i++) print $i}')
    paths=('/')
    unset path
    for part in $parts; do
        path="$path/$part"
        paths=("${paths[@]}" $path)
    done
    ${cmd} ${paths[@]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash with the path given in a shell variable (e.g. $DIR) you can always obtain the last (lowest) path component using the `basename` command and the remaining path up with the `dirname` command:

```
DIR="/home/user/mail/work/spam"
LAST="$( basename "$DIR" )"
DIR=""$( dirname "$DIR" )"
```

results in `$DIR=/home/user/mail/work` and `$LAST=spam`

But why use variables when you can simply walk up the path itself:

```
while [ "/" \!= $(pwd) ] ; do
    (chmod|setfacl|do_anything) .
    cd .. ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use the utility `namei` which is included in util-linux to list the standard Unix permissions:

```
namei -v path
```

Below is another script which does not contain bashisms and should run in any modern Bourne-like shell. For decomposing of the path it uses the standard command `dirname` to gradually strip the last component off until `/` or `.` rests (and the path does not change any further). Just put any code instead of `ls -ld` to perform on all components of the path (e.g. `getfacl`).

```
#!/bin/sh

f="$1"
p=
while test "$f" != "$p" ; do
    ls -ld "$f"
    p="$f"
    f="$(dirname "$f")"
done
```